# Qual a diferença entre IEnumerable, IQueryable e List?

Tags: c#, linq, interface, resharper, enumerable

Qual a diferença entre **IEnumerable**, **IQueryable** e **List** no .NET?

Quando é melhor usar uma ou outra?

Por que o ReSharper me sugere modificar o retorno dessa função, por exemplo, de `List<T>`:

```
private List<User> GetUsers(){ ... }
```

para `IEnumerable<T>`

```
private IEnumerable<User> GetUsers(){ ... }
```

?

Comment: Tem algum resposta que lhe ajudou? Tem algo que eu possa mudar na minha resposta para atender melhor sua necessidade?

Comment: Sim, na verdade todas respostas são muito boas e me ajudaram.  Porém lendo as respostas me surgiram algumas dúvidas que irei tirar quando eu encontrar um tempo.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

A sugestão do Resharper ocorre porque costuma ser [melhor você lidar com interfaces do que tipos concretos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/86484/101), ou analisando de outra forma usar um tipo mais genérico do que um mais específico.

O fato de gerar um [`List<T>`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=net-6.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) não significa que você não tem um objeto que não seja um [`IEnumerable<T>`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.ienumerable-1?view=net-6.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397), afinal `List<T>` **é derivado de** `IEnumerable<T>`. Uma lista é uma coleção que permite que seus membros sejam enumerados, ou seja, que você vá analisando elemento por elemento. Um método [`GetEnumerator()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.ienumerable-1.getenumerator?view=net-6.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397#System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable_1_GetEnumerator) é usado para obter o enumerador (uma espécie de contador para varrer os elementos). E um método `MoveNext()` (da [`IEnumerator`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.ienumerator-1?view=net-6.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397)) faz você avançar para o próximo elemento.

Qualquer objeto `IEnumerable<T>` permite que cada elemento vá sendo processado individualmente para cada operação necessária ao invés de processar todos elementos da coleção em cada operação separada, o que até impediria certas operações de serem realizadas.

Um `IEnumerable<T>` costuma ser bom para **processar elementos que já estão na memória**. Você pode utilizá-lo em uma consulta de banco de dados, mas terá que trazer todos os resultados do banco para a memória para depois processá-lo.

Quando você usa um `.ToList()`, está convertendo o resultado para uma lista. Você não dá um exemplo de utilização, mas acredito pela pergunta que você recebeu um resultado que um [`IQueryable<T>`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.iqueryable-1?view=net-6.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) que é específico para o LINQ. Um `IQueryable<T>` também é derivado de um `IEnumerable<T>` e admite *lazy loading* permitindo uma melhor otimização de uma consulta. Ou seja, apenas os elementos realmente necessários para uma determinada operação são retornados na consulta para futura análise.

A utilização do `IQueryable<T>` permite a construção de árvores de expressões de consulta. Costuma ser mais **adequado para utilização com banco de dados** (LINQ To SQL por exemplo) e outras fontes remotas, principalmente quando precisa de paginação de resultados. Estas expressões podem ser obtidas e executadas com os métodos `IQueryProvider.CreateQuery()` e `IQueryProvider.Execute()`.

Um resultado `IQueryable<T>` pode ser convertido para um `List<T>` mas normalmente é convertido para um `IEnumerable<T>` para dar mais flexibilidade nas operações seguintes.

Veja em exemplo usando um `IEnumerable<T>`:

```
var ent = new EntFuncionarios();
IEnumerable<Funcionario> funcionario = ent.Funcionarios; 
IEnumerable<Funcionario> temp = funcionario.Where(x => x.FuncID == 2).ToList<Funcionario>();
```

Todos os funcionários virão do banco de dados e depois serão analisados um a um no `Where`.

E com `IQueryable<T>`:

```
var ent = new EntFuncionarios();
IQueryable<Funcionario> funcionario = ent.Funcionarios; 
IEnumerable<Funcionario> temp = funcionario.Where(x => x.FuncID == 2).ToList<Funcionario>();
```

Uma consulta SQL é criada e somente os dados necessários são trazidos para análise desta consulta.

A maneira como o filtro de dados funciona é a grande diferença. No segundo caso uma consulta é gerada e somente quando se utiliza o `.ToList<Funcionario>` é que o resultado desta consulta é materializado na memória. Você gera uma consulta e não um resultado final. Este resultado filtrado pode depois ser analisado de forma mais detalhada.

Esta materialização obriga a consulta ser efetivamente executada. Como o `IEnumerable<Funcionario>` e o `IQueryable<Funcionario>` são avaliados tardiamente [(*lazy evaluation*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_evaluation) ou *deferred execution*), ou seja, é avaliado sob demanda, de acordo com a necessidade, você só consegue uma lista real quando você gera essa demanda e isto é efeito com a conversão para uma lista com `.ToList<Funcionario>`.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Linq/IQueryable.cs).

Answer (score 41):

`IEnumerable`, pertence ao namespace [System.Collections](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.collections%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), e que expõe um enumerador, que suporta uma iteração sobre uma simples coleção não genérico (MSDN. Interface IEnumerable, Microsoft. 2014. Disponível em: http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/System.Collections.IEnumerable(v=vs.110).aspx. Acesso em: 27.mai.2014, tradução)  e
`IEnumerable<T>` que pertence ao namespace [System.Collections.Generic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.collections.generic%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) que expõe o enumerador, que suporta uma iteração simples sobre uma coleção de um tipo especificado.(MSDN. Interface IEnumerable`<T>`, Microsoft. 2014. Disponível em: http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/9eekhta0(v=vs.110).aspx. Acesso em: 27.mai.2014, tradução). O `IEnumerable` é a base para todas as coleções que podem ser enumeradas. As interfaces possui um método por padrão a ser implementado o [GetEnumerator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/s793z9y2%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Por essa ilustração percebe a grande importância dessa Interface (`IEnumerable e IEnumerable<T>`)

Figura 1 - "When to use IEnumerable, ICollection, IList and List"
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Fonte: Claudio Bernasconi's TechBlog

`List` representa uma lista de objetos fortemente tipados que podem ser acessados pelo índice. Fornece métodos para pesquisar, ordenar e manipular listas. Esse classe possui várias interfaces que a implementam:

- IList e IList
- ICollection e ICollection
- IReadOnlyList
- IReadOnlyCollection
- IEnumerable
- IEnumerable. (MSDN. Classe List`<T>`. Microsoft. 2014. Disponível em: http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx. Acesso em 27.mai.2014, tradução).

Ou seja, dentro de List existem muitos recursos implementados de várias interfaces. Enquanto o IEnumerable tem o comportamento o List implementa tal comportamento, e também o compilador com IEnumerable adia o trabalho até a sua execução final, enquanto o List você força o compilador a gerar os dados imediatamente. No caso do ReSharper, ele faz uma otimização, e lhe dá no caso a melhor estrutura de trabalho daquele metodo, visto que o `IEnumerable<User>` é bem mais simples do que o `List<User>`.

`IQueryable` fornece a funcionalidade para dar valores a consultas em uma fonte de dados específica no qual o tipo de dados não for especificado. O IQueryable interface herda o IEnumerable interface para que se ele representa uma consulta, os resultados dessa consulta podem ser enumerados. (MSDN. Interface IQueryable, Microsoft. 2014. Disponível em: http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.linq.iqueryable(v=vs.110).aspx. Acesso em: 27.mai.2014, tradução). Como foi dito o IEnumerable é importante para os três itens reportados na questão, é a base dos enumeradores.

*Referências:*

- [`IEnumerable` Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/System.Collections.IEnumerable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
- [`IEnumerable<T>` Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/9eekhta0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
- [Figura 1](http://www.claudiobernasconi.ch/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/Zeichnung-IEnumerable-ICollection-IList.png)
- [Interface IQueryable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.linq.iqueryable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Ótima resposta. Muito bem referencia

Answer (score 27):

`IQueryable` é uma interface mais específica que possui um provedor de consulta, como o LINQ-To-SQL. É um objeto especial, que ao utilizar um método, ele gera uma `query` ou uma estrutura de consulta para uma base de dados e retorna estes resultados como uma lista ou um enumerável.

Embora pareça, ele não necessariamente gera apenas comandos `SQL`: dependendo do provedor de dados, pode-se gerar qualquer consulta através dele, em teoria. Por exemplo, [o MongoDB possui seu próprio provedor que gera comandos num formato próprio](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/use-linq-queries-with-csharp-driver/).

[`IEnumerable` é uma interface que implementa objetos com capacidade de enumeração](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerable.aspx) (`IQueryable` implementa `IEnumerable`, inclusive), ou seja, que define um objeto capaz de relacionar outros objetos em sequência.

Não necessariamente `IEnumerable` é um objeto literal. Em casos em que é usado `yield return` (ou melhor dizendo, usa-se uma função geradora), o que se obtém é um iterador que implementa a interface. Chamadas a este iterador podem devolver um elemento da sequência ou então a sequência toda, dependendo do método utilizado.

A priori, um objeto que implementa `IEnumerable` não supõe necessariamente que ele possa ser modificado. Para estes casos, permitindo ordenação ou manipulação dos objetos contidos dentro da sequência, o recomendado pela linguagem é usar um objeto que implemente `ICollection` ([que por sinal também implementa `IEnumerable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92t2ye13.aspx)).

`List<T>` é a implementação de um objeto da interface `IEnumerable`.

No caso do **ReSharper**, a sugestão ocorre porque `IEnumerable` é mais genérico e justamente suporta o retorno como uma função geradora, e não um objeto definido (`yield return` é a melhor maneira de ilustrar isso).