# Como funciona a lógica do Where no Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, sql, .net, entity-framework, linq

Estou estudando C# e acabo de fazer o minha primeira consulta no Banco Dados:

```
using System;
using System.Data.Entity.Core;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

    namespace Test.Models
    {
        [Table("usuarios")]
        public class Usuario
        {
            [Key]
            public int Id{ set; get; }

            public string Username {
                set;
                get;
            }

            public string Password {
                set;
                get;
            }

            public string Nome {
                set;
                get;
            }

        }
    }
```

No meu `Controller` eu faço assim:

```
var context = new SimpleContext ();

ViewBag.title = "Página inicial";

var usuarios = context.Usuarios
            .Where ((usuario) => usuario.Nome.Contains ("wallace"))
            .OrderBy((usuario) => usuario.Nome)
            .Take (10)
            .ToList ();

return View (usuarios);
```

Eu não cheguei a olhar nenhum tutorial, mas fui tentando fazer a consulta "na sorte" e acabei conseguindo.

Entendi até agora que no método `Where` é esperado que se passe um `lambda`. Outra coisa que entendi é que a expressão que retorna `true` ali dentro serão os dados que serão retornados da tabela.

Mas aí agora surgiu algumas dúvidas:

- Sempre que quero utilizar um `Where`, basta eu fazer algo equivalente  (ou seja, o que eu faria no `Mysql`, traduzindo para `C#`) dentro dessa `lambda` retornando `true` ou `false` para os dados que quero retornar?
- Se eu quisesse usuários que não tenha a palavra `Wallace`, bastaria "negar" o `Contains`?
- Se o `Where` precisa apenas de um `true` ou `false` retornado pelo `lambda`, como é que o `Entity Framework` consegue usar a Sintaxe do C# para fazer a consulta no `Mysql`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- Acho que a primeira pergunta está fazendo uma afirmação correta :P
- A negação do resultado do `Contains()` é uma forma de resolver isso. Pode haver maneiras mais interessantes dependendo do que deseja, mas para o básico, em exemplo simples, é isso.

O LINQ tem um mecanismo sofisticado de criação de [árvores de expressão](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/expression-trees/?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) para gerar a *string* de consulta SQL. Obviamente cada fornecedor de banco de dados precisa ter uma [provedor para o LINQ "ensinando" ele como a árvore de expressão deve gerar um comando SQL adequado](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/bb546158(v=vs.140)?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397). O mesmo valeria para qualquer tipo de consulta que precisaria ser gerada, não só SQL. É possível o programador manipular esta árvore, embora de raro uso.

Há um tutorial no Code Project sobre isto ([Parte 1](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22770/How-To-LINQ-To-SQL-Transformation), [Parte 2](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22799/How-To-LINQ-To-SQL-Transformations-Part-II), [Parte 3](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22819/How-To-LINQ-To-SQL-Part-III)).

Tem outro [tutorial da Microsoft sobre a criação de provedores](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/mattwar/linq-building-an-iqueryable-provider-series?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) de [`IQUeryable`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/17284/101).

O [LINQPad](http://www.linqpad.net/) pode ser seu amigo. Embora seja possível observar pelo *debugger* do Visual Studio se quiser só ver como ficou a consulta gerada.

Note que o LINQ é algo muito mais abrangente do que o `Where` usado no título da questão. Neste caso específico haverá a geração de um `SELECT` com `WHERE`, `ORDER BY` e `LIMIT`. Importante notar também que o `ToList()` é usado para a concretização da lista. É nesse ponto que a consulta será efetivada, muita gente usa quando não precisa da concretização e perde a vantagem da performance em alguns casos.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Esse último parágrafo que fala sobre o Visual Studio ... Minha máquina é linux, só posso usar MonoDevelop... Sniff

Comment: Aí não sei se tem alguma coisa que ajuda. Ainda que dê para desenvolver C# em Linux, a experiência é bem inferior.

Comment: Bem, acho que pelo menos meu virtual box poderá me salvar :)

Comment: Visual Studio em VM? Boa sorte :)

Comment: @bigown já tentou usar o VS em VM ? só curiosidade porque eu ia tentar isso semana que vem nas férias, não funciona?

Comment: Não, mas ele é bem pesado, isto não vai dar certo. Vai funcionar, claro, mas arrume uma manivela, especialmente se a máquina não for nota 10 e a VM não pegar quase toda memória para ela.

Comment: @bigown muito obrigado, vou instalar 2 S.O. vlw.

Comment: @WallaceMaxters, outra alternativa é usar o [`.NET Core`](https://dotnet.github.io/getting-started/) com o [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com) como IDE.

Comment: @TobyMosque, valeu... Ajudou para caramba. Vou dar uma olhada aqui

Comment: O VS Code não se compara com o VS.

Comment: Fiz essa pergunta @TobyMosque http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/125949/alterativas-para-desenvolver-em-c-no-linux

Comment: @bigown, sem sombra de duvidas, mas falando de Linux,  o VS não é uma opção, apenas quiz dizer que o `.NET Code` com `VS Code` é uma opção ao `Mono` com o `MonoDeveloper` para desenvolver aplicações multi-plataforma utilizando `.NET Framework`.

Comment: Calma, galera. Já instalei o Windows 10 na minha máquina :D

Answer (score 3):

Vamos lá

*Sempre que quero retornar um Where, basta eu fazer algo equivalente dentro dessa lambda retornando true ou false para os dados que quero retornar?*

**R:Correto**

Se eu quisesse usuários que não tenha a palavra Wallace, bastaria "negar" o Contains?

**R: Correto**

*Se o Where precisa apenas de um true ou false retornado pelo lambda, como é que o Entity Framework consegue usar a Sintaxe do C# para fazer a consulta no Mysql?*

**R: Ele traduz o LAMBDA para a linguagem do banco (MYSQL), por isso às vezes você nao consegue algumas query lambda quando está buscando no banco**