# Pra que serve o where?

Tags: c#

Já vi em vários códigos de C# o **Where**, mas não entendi sobre ele.

- O que é `algumacoisa.where()` no C#?
- Quando devo ultilizar?
- Pra que serve?

Comment: Relacionada ou duplicata https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/125811/101

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Você tem uma coleção de números.

```
List<int> numeros = new List<int>
{
   1,2,3,4,5
}
```

Você quer uma nova coleção com apenas os números pares a partir da sua lista otiginal

```
var numPares = numeros.Where(x => x % 2 == 0).ToList();
```

A clausula `Where` funciona como um filtro para coleções, nela você passa seu critério para filtrar uma coleção e receber uma nova coleção filtrada a partir da coleção original.

[Veja funcionando no .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/hNN1G3)

**Exemplo com tipo não primitivo:**

No exemplo acima, eu trabalhei com uma lista de `int` (tipo primitivo), e se fosse uma lista de uma classe que eu criei? Tipo uma lista de `Pessoas`?

```
public class Pessoa
{
   public string Nome { get; set; }
   public int Idade { get; set; }
}
```

Supondo que eu tenho uma lista populada:

```
var pessoas = new list<Pessoa>();
// Popula a lista com algumas pessoas...
```

Vamos filtrar:

```
// Pessoas Idosas
var pessoasIdosas = pessoas.Where(x => x.Idade > 60).ToList();

// Pessoas Idosas cujo nome começa com a letra "A"
var pessoasIdosasComNomeComecaLetraA = pessoas.Where(x => x.Idade > 60 && x.Nome.StartsWith("A")).ToList();
```

[Veja funcionando no .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/67absN)

O fato da lista ser tipada (strongly typed) permite que acessamos as propriedades do tipo da coleção genérica (no caso do exemplo, o nome e a idade) para efetuar a filtragem, isso dá um poder e eficiência muito grande para o código.

Answer (score 5):

Where é uma cláusula condicional
Exemplo: Retornar primeiro carro onde o modelo é 'GOL', você pode fazer uma pesquisa sobre Lambda e Linq pra entender mais sobre esses tipos de condições.

```
List<Carro> carros = new List<Carro>();
carros.Where(x=>x.Modelo == "GOL").FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Dica: **`carros.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Modelo == "GOL");`** é bem menos prolixo.