# Como obter a quantidade de "true"?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq

Segue código:

```
int total_true = ctx
    .MinhaTabela
    .Where(x => x.id == 5)
    .Select(x => new Tabela_DTO
    {
        Campo1 = x.Campo1, // database está como true
        Campo2 = x.Campo2, //database está como false
        Campo3 = x.Campo3, //database está como true
        Campo4 = x.Campo4 //database está como true
    })
    .ToArray()
    .Count(x => x == true);
//deve retornar 3;
```

Recebo o erro na linha `.Count(x => x == true);`:

> O operador "==" não pode ser aplicado a operandos dos tipos
>   "Tabela_DTO" e "bool"

Quero saber quantos `true` tem, nesse caso deve retornar `3`.

Segue um exemplo funcional:

```
bool[] testArray = new bool[10] { true, false, true, true, false, true, true, true, false, false };
int i = testArray.Count(x => x== true);
```

A ideia é mesma, porem usando select e tals... e retornar quantos `true` tem no banco de dados. O objetivo é contar quantos `true` tem no banco de dados.

Comment: Já tentou `.Where(x => x.id == 5 && x => x.total_true == true)`?

Comment: @Marconi `x.total_true` não existe.

Comment: `x` será do tipo `Tabela_DTO` que possui os campos `Campo1`, `Campo2`, `Campo3` e `Campo4`. O que você espera comparar com `true` nesse caso?

Comment: @MatheusMiranda eu entendi o que você quer, mas não entendi direito onde quer chegar, poderia explicar melhor sua dúvida?

Comment: @Marconi quero saber quantos valor tem `true`, nesse caso deve retornar `3`.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss eu quero que ele retorne `3`, porque tem 3 valor `true` e 1 `false`.

Comment: @MatheusMiranda você precisa resolver de forma específica esse problema ou quer uma solução mais flexível?

Comment: @RafaelHerik com forma específica fico muito grato.

Comment: @MatheusMiranda acho que não conseguiu expressar sua real necessidade, o seu Where retorna mais de 1 registro? Você usou o .ToArray antes do Count com qual objetivo? A sua tabela "MinhaTabela" tem 4 campos boleanos, seu objetivo é contar quantos desses campos são true apenas?

Comment: @RafaelHerik o objetivo é contar quantos`true` tem. Parece que não existe a forma de fazer direto... Parece que tenho que fazer um `foreach`.

Comment: @MatheusMiranda eu deixei uma resposta ai, fiz o teste com dados na mesma estrutura e funcionou corretamente.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Esse negócio de LINQ para pegar dados do banco de dados não funciona tão bem quanto as pessoas imaginam e traz várias complicações quando sai do trivial, e nem precisa ir muito longe. Este é um caso que parece simples e já complica imensamente. Piora o fato das pessoas não saberem como o LINQ funciona. Na verdade quase todo mundo que sabe evita o seu uso nesta forma, ou só usa em casos muito simples.

Tem várias respostas aqui no SOpt que ensinam usar o LINQ do EF de forma errada, eu mesmo já cai nessa armadilha. A parte mais trágica é que funciona e nem sempre a pessoa se dá conta do estrago que está causando. Alguns usuários estão dando várias respostas ignorando o fato que no EF o LINQ não é traduzido de forma direta.

Para dados em memória é diferente, o LINQ é bem mais útil, porém ele pode ter um custo de performance inadequado.

O LINQ do EF converte a *query* escrita em C# para uma *query* SQL de acordo como provedor. Então precisa ter:

- um código bem feito em C#, o que nem sempre é possível ou fácil de fazer, ainda mais quando não domina muito o LINQ
- um bom provedor de LINQ para o banco de dados, o que também é complicado ter para casos além do trivial
- O LINQ em si ser muito bom, o que não é bem o caso.

Neste caso ou você cria um código em C# que fará o processamento ocorrer na memória, ou seja, ele traz tudo do banco de dados e processa na sua aplicação, que pode ser um tráfego imenso sem necessidade, ou cria uma função no banco de dados que possa fazer uso, o que não é simples fazer o LINQ reconhecer.

Não estou dizendo que é adequado, mas isso deve dar o resultado que quer, mesmo que não de forma boa (não sei afirmar neste caso):

```
int total_true = ctx
    .MinhaTabela
    .Where(x => x.id == 5)
    .Select(x => (x.Campo1 ? 1 : 0) + (x.Campo2 ? 1 : 0) + (x.Campo3 ? 1 : 0) + (x.Campo4 ? 1 : 0)).ToList()[0];
```

Ainda não tenho certeza se isso resolve 100% do que quer, porque não sei se a pergunta está clara. Pode ter alguma pequena diferença.

Por outro lado pode ser que deseje uma coisa diferente do que está na pergunta, aí seria assim:

```
int total_true = ctx
    .MinhaTabela
    .Where(x => x.id == 5)
    .Sum(x => (x.Campo1 ? 1 : 0) + (x.Campo2 ? 1 : 0) + (x.Campo3 ? 1 : 0) + (x.Campo4 ? 1 : 0));
```

Código exemplo (lembrando que se usar reflexão aí funciona bem, mas em banco de dados ([`IQueryable`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/17284/101)) causará [algo trágico para a performance](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/125811/101), o que me faz pensar que todas as respostas que usaram esse recurso estão, no mínimo, causando um efeito ruim, para não dizer errada, já que funciona, mas não produz um resultado aceitável).

```
using static System.Console;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class Program {
    public static void Main(string[] args) {
        var lista = new List<Dados>() {
            new Dados {
                Campo1 = true,
                Campo2 = false,
                Campo3 = true,
                Campo4 = true
            },
            new Dados {
                Campo1 = false,
                Campo2 = false,
                Campo3 = true,
                Campo4 = false
            }
        };
        WriteLine(lista
            .Select(x => (x.Campo1 ? 1 : 0) + (x.Campo2 ? 1 : 0) + (x.Campo3 ? 1 : 0) + (x.Campo4 ? 1 : 0))
            .ToList()[0]);
        WriteLine(lista
            .Sum(x => (x.Campo1 ? 1 : 0) + (x.Campo2 ? 1 : 0) + (x.Campo3 ? 1 : 0) + (x.Campo4 ? 1 : 0)));
    }
}

public class Dados {
    public bool Campo1 { get; set; }
    public bool Campo2 { get; set; }
    public bool Campo3 { get; set; }
    public bool Campo4 { get; set; }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/L5S2Qj). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/qMvTqX). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Linq/CountBooleansFileds.cs).

Note que só o primeiro caso gera o resultado pedido na pergunta. Fiz o outro porque o AP aceitou outra resposta que dá esse resultado.

O primeiro caso pega o caso individual, que é o descrito na pergunta. No segundo pega a soma de todas as linhas. O `Count()` não pode ser usado porque está contando colunas e não linhas, o `Count()` conta linhas. O `Count()` é o mesmo que um `Sum()` onde o valor de cada linha sempre é 1.

Pra falar a verdade eu acho que a maioria dos provedores gerará uma *query* ruim no banco de dados mesmo usando esse modelo sem reflexão, mas já será um pouco melhor. è possível, mas duvido que algum provedor de LINQ de algum banco de dados consiga traduzir esses `if`s em `CASE`s do SQL. O que será trágico. O tempo em centenas de *ms* me parece alto demais, tem algo errado aí, mas com o modelo errado não tem muito o que fazer, precisaria remodelar a base de dados. Eu sempre falo que modelar é o mais importante no desenvolvimento de software. Primeiro faz grandes estruturas de dados, o resto se resolve bem se a base está bem feita.

Comment: A conversão implícita do boleano para inteiro não é permitida dentro da expressão.

Comment: No segundo código : Não é possível converter tipo "bool" em "int".

Comment: Assim funciona: `Convert.ToInt32(x.Campo1) + ...`

Comment: @MatheusMiranda é, misturei linguagens :D

Comment: @Maniero aceitei a sua resposta, porque `.Sum()` fez 467ms e `Select()` fez 386ms. Ou seja, `Select()` é mais rápido :)

Comment: @MatheusMiranda Não é questão de qual é mais rápido e sim que resultado você quer, cada um dá um resultado diferente. Vou atualizar a resposta e mostrar que provavelmente esse tempo é muito longo.

Comment: @MatheusMiranda o seu Where sempre retorna apenas 1 registro, ou você sempre precisa do primeiro? Porque o select funciona nessa situação apenas, no caso o .FirstOrDefault ao Invés do Where é melhor do que usar o ToList()[0] no final.

Comment: @RafaelHerik não entendi muito bem mas ele sempre retorna 1, mais para frente vou querer retornar mais 1., ex: 10 linhas.

Comment: Mas se retornar mais de 1, seu select vai retonar um int[], nesse caso iria precisar do Sum.

Answer (score 1):

De uma forma dinâmica usando o linq você poderia varrer as propriedade de sua classe e verificar quais são do tipo bool e somar as que tem o valor como true.

Veja como eu faria.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var list = new List<Tabela_DTO>()
            {
                new Tabela_DTO()
                {
                    Campo1 = true,
                    Campo2 =false,
                    Campo3 = true,
                    Campo4 = true,
                    Campo5 = false,
                    Campo6 = true,
                    Campo7 = "",
                    Campo8 = 1,
                },
                new Tabela_DTO()
                {
                    Campo1 = false,
                    Campo2 =false,
                    Campo3 = true,
                    Campo4 = false,
                    Campo5 = false,
                    Campo6 = true,
                    Campo7 = "",
                    Campo8 = 2,
                },
            };
            int total_true = list.Select(x => new { total = GetTotal(x) }).Sum(x => x.total);
        }

        static int GetTotal(Tabela_DTO obj)
        {
            int total = 0;
            foreach (PropertyInfo propertyInfo in obj.GetType().GetProperties())
            {
                if (propertyInfo.PropertyType == typeof(bool) && (bool)propertyInfo.GetValue(obj, null) == true)
                {
                    total = total + 1;
                }
            }

            return total;
        }
    }

    public class Tabela_DTO
    {
        public bool Campo1 { get; set; }
        public bool Campo2 { get; set; }
        public bool Campo3 { get; set; }
        public bool Campo4 { get; set; }
        public bool Campo5 { get; set; }
        public bool Campo6 { get; set; }
        public string Campo7 { get; set; }
        public int Campo8 { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Dessa forma evitar de você ter que ficar selecionando os seus campos explicitamente ou alterar a query toda vez que alguma colunar mudar.

Lembrando que não estou usando o linq para entidade e sim para uma list de objeto, você pode dar um .Tolist() na sua tabela antes de usar o exemplo acima.

Answer (score -2):

Segue código:

```
int total_true = ctx
    .MinhaTabela
    .Where(x => x.id == 5)
    .Select(x => new 
    {
        x.Campo1, //true
        x.Campo2, //false
        x.Campo3, //true
        x.Campo4 //true
    })
    .ToArray()
    .Count(x => x.Campo1 == true || x.Campo2 == true || x.Campo3 == true || x.Campo4 == true ||);
//deve retornar 3;
```

Comment: Nesse caso o count vai fazer a verificação por linha, acho que não adiantaria...

Comment: Não é verificação por linha. O objeto `Minha Tabela` e `Tabela_DTO` que você especificou tem as propriedades Campo1 a 4.

Comment: Para cada linha você fez uma operação lógica, a contagem é iterada apenas se o resultado da expressão for verdadeira,  você só adicionou complexidade ao Count com a sua verificação. Para cada item do array ele vai executar a expressão lógica e verificar se itera ou não a contagem.

Comment: Tentei o seu código, ele apenas retorna como 1.