# Como definir a ordem de uma lista dinâmicamente usando Linq e C#

Tags: c#, linq

Olá, estou criando um método para que eu possa retornar uma lista de pessoas onde, eu passo a coluna que deverá ser ordenada e se esta é crescente ou decrescente. Assim:

```
public async Task<List<Pessoa>> getAsync() => await getAsync("id", false);
public async Task<List<Pessoa>> getAsync(string order) => await getAsync(order, false);
public async Task<List<Pessoa>> getAsync(string order, bool desc)
{
    using (var context = Context())
    {
        try
        {
            var list = context.ContaBancaria.AsNoTracking();

            return desc ? 
                await list.OrderByDescending(x => x.GetType().GetProperty(order))
                    .ToListAsync() :
                await list.OrderBy(x => x.GetType().GetProperty(order))
                    .ToListAsync();

            }
        catch
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Minha dúvida é se existe alguma forma de eu decidir a ordenação da lista (ou seja, ou utilizar o método `OrderBy` ou o `OrderByDescending` de uma forma mais "dinâmica" do que esta?

**NOTA:** quando digo dinâmica, eu digo na economia de código. Pensei em criar um método `OrderBy` que aceite mais um campo, este sendo a referência de crescente ou decrescente e, nesse método fazer o tratamento. Assim seu uso seria algo desse tipo:

```
public async Task<List<Pessoa>> getAsync() => await getAsync("id", false);
public async Task<List<Pessoa>> getAsync(string order) => await getAsync(order, false);
public async Task<List<Pessoa>> getAsync(string order, bool desc)
{
    using (var context = Context())
    {
        try
        {
            var list = context.ContaBancaria.AsNoTracking();

            return await list
                .OrderBy(x => x.GetType().GetProperty(order), desc)
                .ToListAsync();
        catch
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Como eu sempre falo e ninguém ouve, depende. Se fará isso na mmória, ou seja, usar um `IEnumerable` beleza uma solução assim, se vai fazer no banco de dados, ou seja, um `IQueryable` é diferente, precisa fazer uma tradução para o provedor e isso pode criar um código horrível e nada performático., principalmente usando reflexão (que já deve ser evitado mesmo na memória, é absurdamente lento).

Comment: Não entendi... sinceramente. A questão que levantei é que, tenho 2 métodos já existentes no Linq e que quero transformar em somente 1, onde dependendo do parâmetro que passar (true/false) ele vai chamar um ou outro. Não vejo porque esse raciocínio sendo que não vou refazer o EF

Comment: Veja https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/319077/101, https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/182176/101, https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/125811/101. Se não entender faça uma pergunta específica. pra falar a verdade eu acho que ninguém deveria usar o LINQ sem entender as cosias, estão fazendo coisas horríveis e lentas que doem.