# Where não funciona ao listar todos os registros - Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

Preciso retornar todos os registros que contenham a filial informada usando a cláusula `where`, só que o Entity Framework está retornando todos os registros ignorando o que está no `where`. Onde estou errando?

```
public IQueryable<PessoaGenerico> GetAllPessoaGenericoByFilial(int id)
{
  return DbSet
   .Where(pg => pg.PessoaFilialId == id)
   .AsQueryable()
   .AsNoTracking();
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No exemplo, eu estou buscando todos os registros onde `PessoaFilialId` é igual a 31. Ele deveria não encontrar e retornar `null`, mas está trazendo todos.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Faltou o `ToList()`. Acontece que o `IQueryable` ele apenas cria a consulta, ela de fato será executada quando você "indicar" isso com o `ToList()` ou um `FirstOrDefault()`, por exemplo.

Para verificar se há valor, você pode usar o método `Any()`, que irá retornar `true` caso tenha valor, exemplo:

```
if (suaLista.Any()) {
    //Possui valor
}
```

Sugestão de leitura:
[Qual a diferença entre IEnumerable, IQueryable e List?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/17284/qual-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-ienumerable-iqueryable-e-list)

<sub>Talvez outra pessoa saiba explicar melhor e com mais detalhes, mas em suma é isso.</sub>

Comment: Obrigado pelo retorno @Barbetta, mas não funcionou com o ToList(). Ele continua trazendo todos os registros.... estranho isso...

Comment: @JalberRomano que estranho, não vejo mais nada de diferente no código.. vamos fazer alguns testes rsrs, tente assim `public List<SuaClasse> GetAllPessoaGenericoByFilial(int id)
        {
            return DbSet.Where(pg => pg.PessoaFilialId == id).AsNoTracking().ToList();
        }` alterando o método diretamente.

Outra coisa, esse `DbSet` onde vc forma ele?

Comment: acho que descobri o problema... Eu estava validando dentro de um if (com a minha função do repositório e o retorno não era null... O retorno está vindo (Empty = "Enumeration yielded no results")... Por que que em alguns casos o retorno é null e em outros Empty? OCmo eu trato o empty?

Comment: Pera, vamos separar os casos, ali no print seu está retornando valor, após usar o `ToList()` parou de vir valor? ou mesmo com o `IQueryable` está retornando `Empty`?

Comment: Não. É que eu estava validando assim: "if ( _pessoaGenericoRepository.GetAllPessoaGenericoByFilial(pessoaGenerico.PessoaId) != null)". Quando eu "debbugava" e posicionava o mouse sobre pessoaGenericoRepository, eram retornados todos os registros (com ou sem o ToList), mas era pq a função estava dentro do If. Agora eu valido assim: " var teste = _pessoaGenericoRepository.GetAllPessoaGenericoByFilial(pessoaGenerico.PessoaId);
            if (teste != null)" e o retorno é Empty , pois Ienumerable e IQuerable retornan Empty quando não encontrado... Preciso apenas tratar quando for empty....

Comment: Em resumo: Preciso tratar o retorno "Empty", isto é, se o retorno for diferente de empty....

Comment: Eu editei a resposta com o um If(lista.Any()), ,tenta ele para vermos se vai dar certo

Comment: Funcionou 100%!!!! Obrigado Mano!!!