# Propriedade com GET (GetterOnly) com IQueryable linq C#

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

Não sei exatamente como se chama quando mapeia o retorno no método assim, mas vou tentar explicar, Eu tenho a seguinte classe por exemplo:

```
public class Venda(){
   public decimal Valor {get;set;}
   public decimal Desconto {get;set;}
   public decimal ValorLiquido => Valor - Descontos;
}
```

Eu uso EntityFramework e essa classe seria uma model do Banco de Dados, preciso fazer um relatorio de vendas e nesse relatorio eu uso a Propriedade ValorLiquido e o problema esta ai faço a seguinte consulta:

```
var vendas = ctx.Vendas;
```

Isso me retorna uma Iqueryable ate ai tudo bem, porem se eu tento usar a propriedade ValorLiquido me retorna a seguinte mensagem:

> The specified type member 'ValorLiquido' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported.

Se eu der `ToList()` passa a funcionar e consigo acessar a propriedade, só que é um relatorio com mais de 50mil itens, e na classe real, existe umas 10 Propriedade GetterOnly pra mais, então é inviável usar `ToList()`,
A questão é:
Teria alguma forma de acessar essa propriedade sem dar ToList() no caso numa lista IQueryAble?

Comment: Porque não utilizas uma View que carrega os teus dados já calculados, logo o output muito menor, (calculas no servidor), ao invés de carregares 50K de registos...e quando chegar aos 10 milhões? O que fazes?

Comment: Teria como parametrizar essa view pela aplicação? No caso deste relatorio o Usuario pode escolher os filtros, como data, forma de pagamento e etc

Comment: As Views são como uma query normal a uma tabela, mas permite mapear o teu output (só retornas o que queres que vejam/acedam), fazer joins com outras tabelas, cálculos, agregar dados etc, doc microsoft https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-view-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017. A sua utilização em SQL é como efetuares um select a uma tabela to tipo SELECT * FROM [View_Name] WHERE User LIKE '%An%', a sua utilização em EF, tens num post aqui https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7461265/how-to-use-views-in-code-first-entity-framework.

Comment: uma view carrega todos os dados antes de fazer os filtros, vai te dar dor de cabeça, se quiser diminuir o result set use um where no seu linq ex : .where(x=>x. valorliquido=10).ToList()

Comment: @EdenilsonBila de uma lida nisso: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/17284/qual-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-ienumerable-iqueryable-e-list   O IQueryable é uma arvore de consulta, os dados não foram "materializados" ainda. por isso não é possível acessar o propriedade ValorLiquido

Answer (score 0):

Já tentou ignorar o mapeamento desse campo no Entityframework adicionando o atributo 'NotMapped' ?

Exemplo:

```
public class Venda(){
   public decimal Valor {get;set;}
   public decimal Desconto {get;set;}
   [NotMapped]
   public decimal ValorLiquido => Valor - Descontos;
}
```